# Proxy setting for powershell connecting to outlook.office365

Tags: powershell, proxy, office365, exchange-server

I'm working on PowerShell script that connect to outlook office365(exchange online) as follows:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential $credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

Now the problem is I want to connect via a proxy server with authentication, so did the following

```
$proxy = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy "http://myproxy:80"
$proxy.Credentials = $cred
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = $proxy
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential 
$credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

But it doesn't connect via proxy that I set. So I did the following:

```
$proxy = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy "http://myproxy:80"
$proxy.Credentials = $cred
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = $proxy
$sessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -ProxyAccessType IEConfig
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential 
$credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -SessionOption $sessionOption
```

But still doesn't pass through proxy.

I also tried to use `netsh winhttp set proxy "myproxy:80"` and it passed through the proxy server but it seems it doesn't have authentication.

Is there any way to explicitly set the proxy for New-PSSession cmdlet?
Note: I don't want to set proxy setting on IE, just want to explicitly set proxy per session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did and it seems working.

```
$proxyAddress = $proxyHost + ":" + $proxyPort
netsh winhttp set proxy $proxyAddress
$proxysecpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $proxyPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$proxycred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($proxyUser, $proxysecpasswd)
$sessionOpts = New-PSSessionOption -ProxyAccessType WinHttpConfig -ProxyCredential $proxycred -ProxyAuthentication Basic

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($userId, $secpasswd)
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $credential -Authentication "Basic" -AllowRedirection -SessionOption $sessionOpts
```

Please make some comments if there are any other better ways or if this will pose any other problems that I should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the following:

1.) Set proxy via NETSH

2.) Inside your powershell approach use:

```
$webclient=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$creds=Get-Credential
$webclient.Proxy.Credentials=$creds
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it seems the $webclient is not being used in New-PSSession cmdlet. Any other way?